# How to place Laravel and use artisan commands?

Tags: php, frameworks, laravel

I'm trying laravel php framework recently. I'm using Windows 7 and XP (tries to install it on both), XAMPP 1.8.1 and PHP 5.4.7.

So confusing.

1. In many articles (including laravel's documentation itself), I meet up many artisan codings.
   What is artisan? I can't define it myself so clear. I end up with articles that not giving any simple explanation.
   I got commands tutorials like `php artisan key:generate` and else.
   But I always failed, with this error on Command Prompt : `'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.
   I got solution like "change directory to laravel root",
   So, I `chdir`-ed to C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\public\ but nothing works.
2. I that right to access my laravel site with browser via `localhost/laravel/public/`?
   So, if I try to upload it to my public site, I should place those items in my root folder (/)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are getting the error when calling php.exe because windows command prompt is not tracking your PHP installation. You can fix that by adding it into PATH environment variable:

Go to "My Computer" > "Properties" > "Advanced" > "Environment Variables" > "Path", add a semicolon (;) at the end and then path to your PHP binaries folder, which in your case is C:\xampp\php

After you restart the command prompt PHP and Artisan should work fine.

As to your second question, "public" folder should be your server's (or virtual host's) DocumentRoot. There is no need to expose the whole framework on your web server.

Comment: work like a candy! thanks a lot.... and, about the 2nd question, public should be on the main folder site, so the assets other that public folder cant be accessed, am i right? anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: Correct. For example, your DocumentRoot can be `C:\xampp\projects\projectname\public` and the framework will be in `C:\xampp\projects\projectname`. This way the framework cannot be accessed from your website and you could, for example, have a git repository there.

Answer (score 4):

1. The `artisan` command has to be parsed through a php interpreter, thats why you call it like `php artisan...`

   I think, you have to use the php.exe to make it work on Windows.
   Some thing like `c:\path\to\php.exe artisan command`
2. Read through the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/install) and the [Code happy](http://codehappy.daylerees.com/getting-started) book by Dayle Rees, to understand the public folder and how to setup a Virtual host for your development